# End Tick Mark Not Showing in Tikz Image

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to create an empty box for my students to draw their own box-and-whiskers plot on an assignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\centerline{
\resizebox{15cm}{5cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [ytick={\empty},yticklabels={,,},
   ytick style={draw=none}, xmin = -1, xmax = 70,
  xtick = {-10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40,50,60, 70},
xticklabels={-10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40,50,60,70}]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem here is that I want the tick marks to be 0,10,20,30,40,50,60.  However, when I have the actual box-and-whiskers plotted in a separate image I get the correct bounds:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}

\centerline{
\resizebox{15cm}{5cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
    ytick={0},
   xtick = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40 ,50 ,60}
    ]
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=38,
      upper quartile=46,
      lower quartile=18,
      upper whisker=59,
     lower whisker=1
    },
    ] coordinates {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} }
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I amend the blank image so that the tick marks range from 0 to 60?

Comment: is plotting in white color okay for you `;)`? would be an easier way to not diplay the image `:D`. If so, add `color=white` in `\addplot+[options]{...}`

Comment: @Raaja Lol, I guess that's one way to do it.  But it would be nice to get an explanation for why TeX is behaving the way it is.

Comment: I will wait for an answer from`TikZperts`.

Comment: why the `\resizebox`? as you see in the image it horribly distorts the text and will also distort the line thickness of any plots making vertical and horizontal lines have different widths.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want the resize box because I want my students to have plenty of room to draw their solution.  I don't particularly care that the numbers are distorted.  Without the resize box then the space is too small.

Comment: @Mnifldz it would be better to make the box of the required size rather than make one of the wrong size and distort it. I leave it to others to know the required tikz details:-)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ytick=\empty,
    ymin=0,ymax=1, % <-- added
    xmin = -1,
    xmax = 61, % modified
    xtick = {0, 10, ..., 60}, % modified
    width=\textwidth,  % <-- added
    height=0.3\textwidth % <-- added
]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```